# App Engine - file conversion

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using from google.appengine.api import conversion

To allow me to convert an HTML email into a PDF file. The code is below and it works.
However the width of the PDF document slices off the right hand side of my document.

Amy clues how to fix this

```
    asset = conversion.Asset("text/html", message.html, "test.html")
    conversion_obj = conversion.Conversion(asset, "application/pdf")
    result = conversion.convert(conversion_obj)
    if result.assets:
        for asset in result.assets:
            message.attachments=message.attachments+[(BnPresets.email_filename[0:BnPresets.email_filename.find('.')]+".pdf",asset.data)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like you cannot control the **width** (or dimensions) of converted PDF documents. Seems like you can only do this with `.png` images. Some [extra conversion options](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/overview.html#Additional_Functions):

- The width of output images (`*.png` only)
- A specific page or page range to output to an image (`*.png` only)
- The language of source text for OCR operations (`*.txt`, `*.html`, and `*.pdf` only)

Note that one way around this *could* be to convert your html page to a png image (with the correct width), and then [re-convert this png image to a pdf document](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/overview.html#Conversion_Paths). I wouldn't advise you to use this method because you would end up using **two** API calls per conversion, which gets expensive really quickly.

A better way would be to structure the dimensions of your *input* html page properly such that one-off conversions to PDF documents end up being pretty much identical.